# Error at eth_estimateGas & eth_call geth local testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, clique, geth-clique, eth-call

Here I am asking for help for my problem, namely to eth_call and eth_estimateGas. So I created LocalTestnet with the aim of making a Swap Testnet, but when I run it an error appears like the one I input. please help to find this problem.

[image: Problem With Geth]

I share the manual geth configuration, for the genesis.json file I built using puppeth

```
geth --datadir=node2/ \
    --syncmode 'full' \
    --port 30311 \
    --networkid 14093 \
    --http \
    --http.addr 0.0.0.0 \
    --http.corsdomain '*' \
    --http.port 8546 \
    --http.vhosts '*' \
    --http.api admin,eth,miner,net,txpool,personal,web3,debug \
    --ws.api eth,net,web3,debug,txpool \
    --ws \
    --ws.addr 0.0.0.0 \
    --ws.port 8456 \
    --ws.origins '*' \
    --authrpc.addr 0.0.0.0 \
    --authrpc.port 8552 \
    --mine \
    --miner.gasprice 1000000000 \
    --miner.gaslimit 30000000 \
    --rpc.gascap 0 \
    --rpc.txfeecap 0 \
    --txpool.pricelimit 1 \
    --txpool.pricebump 10 \
    --gpo.blocks 20 \
    --gpo.percentile 60 \
    --cache 1024 \
    --verbosity 3 \
    --allow-insecure-unlock \
    --unlock "xxxxxx" \
    --password password.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: You may not have enough tokens or you didn't approve the contract.

Comment: Thanks for Answer mate, I don't see that there is no balance. and now the problem is solved